# Reverse for 'post/profile/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'user': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, reverse

i have a problem in my django project. when i want show posts that belongs to specific user id this show me this error

urls.py:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<user>\d+)/$', profile)
```

views.py:

```
def profile(request, user=None):

    queryset = Post.objects.filter(user=user)

    context ={

    "object_list" : queryset,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

html page:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <li><a href=" {% url 'post/profile/' user=request.user.id %} ">My ADS</a></li>
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """docstring for Post"""

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'user/',null=True, blank=True, height_field="height_field", width_field="width_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.post_title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detailpost", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

Comment: Try do the same as in Daniel's answer but also check main project's url.py file. Do you set namespace for the application urls? If yes you should do this: {% url 'app_namespace:profile' user=request.user.id %} where app_namespace is namespace from main url.py

Comment: @neverwalkaloner yes you right, that work thankssss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{% url %}` tag takes the name of the URL pattern, not the path. You should give the pattern an name:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<user>\d+)/$', profile, name='profile')
```

and use the tag like this:

```
{% url 'profile' user=request.user.id %}
```

Comment: i wrote but did not worked .. i use include url therefor i used "post/profile"